# Can directory listing be disabled for sftp?

Tags: sftp, openssh

A question arose in a group discussion: Can directory listing be disabled for sftp while still retaining read and write access?

We are using openssh on ubuntu server 11.02 if that helps.

Comment: Why not remove directory search permissions? (`chmod a-x <dirname>`?)

Comment: @Mikel, but then you can also not `cd` any more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove Read access.

- Read access on a directory means that you can see a listing of files within that directory.
- Execute (X) access means you can cd into the directory or traverse it
- Write access means that you are able to add or change items within the directory.

Comment: Thanks! Read access was the solution. For interested reader, the command to remove read access from all users is `chmod -r folder_name`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so.

I found nothing in the sshd_config man-page that gives a hint about restricting sftp-commands (like the restricitons you can impose on some ftp-daemons).

I have not tested this, but perhaps you can alias the `ls` command to something that does nothing in ssh-context (so either in .sshrc or via forced-command).

Answer (score 0):

I just recently set up a chroot sftp system, and as I was testing, I noticed that a chrooted user with a shell of /bin/false was not able to executer `ls` without getting kicked out. The sshd_config is also using internal-sftp-server.

I haven't had time to investigate it yet, but I suspect that internal-sftp-server is trying to spawn a sub-shell, and is being denied, since the user's shell is /bin/false. It's just a theory.

FWIW, my user's home directory is root:root 755.